# ASP.NET web service and page method

Tags: asp.net

For the moment, I have a page method that I call with javascript/jQuery and the server returns a json object. I'm realizing that I'd actually like to have this page method on every page. Of course, I could copy paste the page method on every page but I'm looking into better options.

1. Putting the page method in the master page. Is this easy to do?
2. Creating a web service. My question is this: for now, the page knows which client is requesting the method through the sessionID; does a web service also know who's calling it? In term of performance, are they comparable?

Let me know you have any suggestions and what I should watch out for.

Thanks.

Comment: Reason number #102 in Why I Hate WebForms: you have to jump through so many hoops just to do something simple liking making a request to a simple, shared service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that functionality on every page , that means there is a common functionality you need on every page right.

In your webservice you can expose multiple bindings , once for javascript/jquery which can be json object and again you can use the same for your html aslo.

Add the reference as service reference or webreference in your project. Once it is added it will be availble on every page and you can use the method on all the pages you want.

Let me know you need more details on this.

try something like this

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public List<Object> GetData(int pageSize)
    {

    }

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.asmx/yourmethodname",
    data: "{'somevalue':'14'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
      // response...here
    },
    error: function(msg) {
// error here
    }
});
```

Comment: agree - go with a webservice, but there is not a need to create a separate web service project for a single service; a single service can be added as an item to @frenchie's existing web project

Comment: ok, looks like a web service might work better. How do I make the web service return json instead of XML?

Comment: @frenchie , what are you using , i think as you said webmethod you might be using .aspmx right.. you can do it very easily as a string with json format , otherwise i think .asmx supports json endpoint. I am using wcf and it automatiicaly exposes json end point.

Comment: At the moment, I'm using an aspx file and I put a web method inside. Are web services secure?

Comment: @frenchie , can you explain your requirement more clear , i can guide you some good solution.

Comment: A doctor has patient appointments: he clicks on a date in a calendar and the appointments of that date come back in the form of a json string that gets parsed into html for display in a popup that's on every page.

Comment: @frenchie , if your date picker is a pure html or jquery one , this is the best place to implement or reuse. Assume your .aspx or .asmx or .wcf has method like GetAppointments(Data date) which takes a date as parameter. Use jquery's ajax and make a call to service.

Comment: For now it works like you described and it's using a pagemethod. Do you think it's better to change to a web service or a page method in the master page?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the object oriented thing and create a base page that all of your other pages inherit from.  Something like:

```
     public partial class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
        {

            [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
            public static string MyCallbackMethod(string someVar)
            {
                ...
            }   
         }
```

And then the BasePage would be used by the other pages:

```
public partial class Default : BasePage 
        {
                ...
```